# Baking Normal map in wrong position

Tags: baking

Recently, I baked a normal map from high poly mesh to low poly one, and I got this. I've searched on the Internet, but still can't find solution.
[image]

Comment: have you tried to increase the Ray Distance a bit?

Comment: The problem here is that the wheel is baked on plate. Besides, I've changed Ray Distance to 10.